# Hashicorp's Vault CLI does not store authentication token in token helper

Tags: ssl, hashicorp-vault, vault, mtls

After I login to my Vault with TLS authentication

```sh
vault login -method=cert \
            -ca-cert=/path/to/ca/cert \
            -client-cert=/path/to/client/cert \
            -client-key=/path/to/client/key
```

I would expect the returned token to be updated at `~/.vault-token`. However it is not. For instance, running `$ vault status` returns

```sh
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I can work around this by adding `-ca-cert=path/to/ca/cert` to every subsequent requests but it is not ideal. Any idea what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I had installed Vault CLI with snap package manager. The problem seems to be created by it.

Removing that installation (don't forget to remove `~/snap/vault` folder) and then installing it via apt-get fixed the issue.